# how to add space or padding between cloned objects through jquery

Tags: jquery, clone, html-table, padding

following is my cloning code

```
var zero=0;
  var rownum=0;
   $("#btn11").click(function(){
    //Creating New row , then cloning elements one by one, and changing the id of elements......
        var newrow = $('#row'+ rownum );
        newrow.clone().attr('id', 'row'+(++rownum) ).insertAfter( newrow);

        var uncode = $('#uncode'+ zero );
        uncode.clone().attr('id', 'uncode'+rownum ).insertAfter( newrow )[0];

        var purpose = $('#purpose'+ zero );
        purpose.clone().attr('id', 'purpose'+rownum ).insertAfter( newrow )[0];



    });
```

i am using this code to clone objects, how can i align or add padding or add  . any thing would be helpful

Comment: Can you pls add some sample html?

Answer (score 2):

Padding is css property so you need to do this using **.css()**

```
 var new_row = $('#row'+ rownum );
 var clone_row = newrow.clone();
 clone_row.attr('id', 'row'+(++rownum) );
 clone_row.css('padding', '5px' );
//If you want to add more than one css style
//clone_row.css({
//'padding': '5px',
//'background':'cyan'
//});

clone_row.insertAfter(new_row);
```